# Counter example for the limit comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Q.** Given that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n $ satisfy $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1 $, is there an example of series that do not converge or diverge together?

$a_n , b_n$ are not necessarily positive therefore not stisfies the conditions for the limit comparison test.

Comment: @SangchulLee  yes I know that, can you help me find an example?

Comment: I added a concrete counter-example and moved it to an answer.

Comment: @SangchulLee  thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If $(a_n)$ or $(b_n)$ are eventually positive, then no. If you allow them to have both positive and negative terms infinitely often, then there are counter-examples. For example, consider

$$
a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{2n}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
b_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}.
$$

Then $a_n/b_n \to 1$ and $\sum_n b_n$ converges by the alternating series test, but $\sum a_n$ diverges.